# K ef command gives "k : System.Exception: Unable to locate project.json "

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When i try to add a migration, "k" gives me the following error:

```
k : System.Exception: Unable to locate project.json
At line:1 char:1
+ k web
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Exceptio...te project.json:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

bij Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.Initialize(DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices)
bij Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost..ctor(DefaultHostOptions options, IService
Provider hostServices)
bij Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Here is my global.json:

```
{
"projects": [ "src", "FoodDelivery" ],
"sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
    }
}
```

I have the following directory structure

```
FoodPick
FoodPick/src
FoodPick/src/FoodDelivery
FoodPick/src/FoodDelivery/project.json
FoodPick/src/FoodShare
FoodPick/artifacts
FoodPick/global.json
```

I want to execute the k ef migration add from the FoodDelivery project, which contains a project.json

Here is the contents of project.json.

Alternatively, i executed the command through the command console ( cmd.exe). The following is the error i receive.

[image: k ef error in cmd.exe]

This is the error i receive when i run kpm restore

```
PM> kpm restore
Restoring packages for D:\Projects\Visual Studio\Foodpick\src\AddressLookup\project.json
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.SqlServer'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.SqlServer'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.SqlServer'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.Commands'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.Commands'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.Commands'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles'.
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles'
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console'.
  CACHE http://default-nuget.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader'.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Commands
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.SqlServer
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.Commands'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.SqlServer'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.SqlServer
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='EntityFramework.SqlServer'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Error: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.SqlServer
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
----------
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Logging
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
   bij System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>d__21.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RemoteWalkProvider.<FindLibrary>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibrary>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryByVersion>d__8.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryMatch>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__62.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommand>d__61.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.Logging'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.).
Error: FindPackagesById:
```

Now i read that the current command,instead of "k ef migration add the_migration_name", is "dnvm ef migration add the_migration_name"

dnvm is already installed, but the command is just not working ( if this would be the way to go)...

I'd like to know what could be wrong and help my in my further quest :p

Comment: The problem would be that it can't **find** the file.  In other words, the file is not in the place or places where it is looking for it.  (Hint: it is unlikely to be looking for files in your source tree ... because your source tree is unlikely to be there at runtime.)

Comment: Probably being stupid right now. But i use Package Manager Console and select the src\FoodDelivery as default project. Then i use "k ef" and it can't find the file. I read somewhere that a mistake in global.json can be the cause of this (that's why i added it). But i don't see why it can't find the file... It's just there :p . The command is not executed with the project at runtime, but during development.

Comment: `k`-commands have been renamed: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since beta4, there have been some renames:

- `k` -> `dnx`
- `kpm` -> `dnu`
- `kvm` -> `dnvm`

If you still have some of the old applications, edit the `PATH` environment variable and remove anything related to `.k`

Answer (score 0):

Correct command to use is :

```
dnx . ef migration add initial //NEW & working through cmd.exe in the projects directory 

k ef migration add //OLD -- DO NOT USE -- Doesn't work anymore
```